# C# not receiving JSON string from localhost webpage

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am trying to get JSON data from a web page on my localhost web server using xamarin for android with c#. The web-page runs a SQL query based on the value in the URL's query string and gets all necessary data.

The url I am using to get the JSON

```
http://localhost/api/index.php?search=testo
```

The JSON result which is echo'd

```
{"name":"testo","description":"testo","price":"2","quantity":"3","dateadded":"2018-04-10"}
```

The code below is the method that I am calling in onCreate to be executed

```
private void getResponse()
    {
        output.Text = "You have searched for: " + "'" + search + "'";
        try
        {
            //the value of 'search' is the product they searched for 
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            var data = c.DownloadString("http://localhost/api/index.php?search=" + search);
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

            nameField.Text = o["name"].ToString();
            descrField.Text = o["description"].ToString();
            priceField.Text = o["price"].ToString();
            quantityField.Text = o["quantity"].ToString();
            dateField.Text = o["dateadded"].ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            nameField.Text = "Product not found.";
            descrField.Text = "Product not found."; 
            priceField.Text = "Product not found.";
            quantityField.Text = "Product not found.";
            dateField.Text = "Product not found.";
        }
    }
```

The current response from this application is that the product was not found (when it does exist), I don't think it is gathering the JSON at all which would explain it not working - if you guys have any idea i would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: put an `(Exception Ex)` on your catch block and debug it to see what error your getting

Comment: @mituw16 System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b6] in <6c708cf596db438ebfc6b7e012659eee>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0016d] in <6c708cf596db438ebfc6b7e012659eee>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: I am using wamp, if there is a way to allow connections.

Comment: How about using the ip address directly?

Comment: @frz3993 same error unfortunately ;(

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html tried this, changing the localhost ip from 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2 as apparently its the "Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)" on android emulators, i debugged it and it gave me this:

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002b3] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonLoadSettings settings) [0x00013]

Comment: you need to examine the data that is actually being returned by your service.  I'd guess it's returning an HTML error page, not the actual json you expect

Comment: Instead of passing the value of the search box into the download string I gave it the URL that I know gives valid JSON data and still get the same error, I'll post an update of my code soon and show you my progress.

Comment: if you're getting that same error then you're NOT getting valid json.   You need to validate the result that is actually returned by your actual code, not what you think is returned.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was with HTML tags, it was trying to parse the html elements such as html, head, body etc which wouldn't work! Just had to remove this from the index file and it worked. Thanks @Jason for the idea about testing the result.